# MPTT Algorith VS Data Normalization

Tags: mysql, normalization, mptt

Lets say I am trying to store addresses in a database that look like this:

```
123 Some Street
Placeville, Idaho
83201, USA
```

What would be the best practice way of storing this in a relational database like MySQL?

Typically I would normalize it into several separate tables like this:

```
| Region Table | <-- store state/province
| City         | <-- Store city 
| Address      | <-- Store Street Address
```

I can then use joins to assemble a complete address while still giving the flexibility of data normalization for reporting and such.

That being said I have also realized I can use the MPTT algorithm to store the address structure in a tree:

```
USA
|
+-Idaho
   |
   +-City 1
   |   |
   |   +-Address 1
   |
   +-City 2
       |
       +-Address 2
```

My question is, is there any reason to select one method over the other?

Comment: Are you talking about a specific address of a user or an address directory? If the former: try creating actual tables for it. If the latter: Are you aware that your first version is actually a tree too (a linked list)? You e.g. certainly need to add a column in `city` that tells you it's `region`. If not, think about it. If you *are* aware: yes, you can store data in both kind of trees if you want. Your first model is *much* simpler though *AND* provides everything you need (e.g. you do not need to have an order between two children, you do not need unlimited depth, ...).

Comment: Yes in both cases the address is a tree. Essentially in my use case I will be doing largely more reading of addresses than updating or adding them. I guess my question is for very frequent reading is MPTT and a single table better, worse or the same as using linked tables?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your intentions. The difference between the two approaches is not if you have one or three tables. You can store the first tree in one table too: `(id, parent, ...)`, e.g. `1, null, country`, `2, 1, region`, `3, 2, city`. The problem is the column definition for `...` (which is the identical to your mptt approach), and I urge you (again) to try to create the actual table for it. Both ways to define the columns have flaws which can be solved by, surprise, creating 3 tables. Please try it!

Comment: And just to be sure there is no misunderstanding: this is for an address directory. For an actual address of e.g. a customer, you will store it in one row like `(customerid, country, region, city, zipcode, street, number)`. You use the directory to verify that the address is valid (e.g. that zipcode/city, or that a streetname exists in a city), but you will not store it in a tree; while you *could* leave out e.g. country/region and just store zipcode+city or even just the streetid (and look the rest up in the directory on the fly), that's usually not done for other reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments! I have gone with the 3 table approach.